# Словообразование

Tags: словообразование

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста,разобраться, как образовано слово ПОДБЕРЕЗОВИК: от слова БЕРЕЗА или от слова БЕРЕЗОВЫЙ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Источник: Т.Ф. Ефремова "Толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц",
  ПОД...ОВИК - нерегулярная словообразовательная единица используется в названиях грибов, при образовании применяется основа существительного. Таким образом, береза - подберезовик. Суммарные суффиксы часто используются в русском языке, например: торф - торфяник, путешествовать - путешественник.

С грибом подберезовиком деваться некуда: здесь решающее значение имеет то, что словообразовательная единица составная (ПОД….ОВИК). Единичный суффикс ОВИК  (в форме ЕВИК) выделяется в слове большевик (больше – большевик).  Таким образом, суммарные суффиксы ВСЕГДА выделяются в том случае,  если  слово с промежуточной формой отсутствует: задача – задачник – суффикс НИК. В то же время в словаре Ефремовой при определении суффикса явно учитывается словообразовательный анализ, то есть какой частью речи  мотивировано слово, например: сон – сонник (книга с толкованиями снов), образование сущ.→сущ., суффикс НИК, хотя промежуточное слово сонный существует. Для сравнения: в слове фронтовик выделяются два суффикса ОВ+ИК.

При словообразовательном анализе надо найти мотивирующее слово, определить способ образования и используемые морфемы. Подберезовик: мотивирующее слово береза, способ образования префиксально-суффиксальный, приставка ПО + суффикс ОВИК. Слова подберезовый нет в словарях, да и откуда ему там взяться. Значение его непонятно, словообразование тоже.Приставка ПОД без суффикса до сих пор использовалась только для образования существительных от существительных: группа -   подгруппа. Вариант березовый - подберезовый будет первым.Допустим, кому-то хочется сказать "подберезовый гриб". Но это единственное употребление этого слова, больше ничего "подберезового" в природе нет.Но и тогда мы имеем береза - подберезовый, а не березовый - подберезовый.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Но однозначного ответа, наверное, нет?

Answer (score 7):

Существуют разные подходы к морфемному и словообразовательному анализу, поэтому в разных словарях можно увидеть разное членение одного и того же слова.  Мне близок тот подход, которому меня научили в университете. Идем от значения слова. Что такое подберезовик? Гриб. который растет под березами. Значит, **слово *подберезовик* образовано от слова *береза***. Сравниваем со словом* подберезовик*.* Под *- приставка,* овик *- суффикс. Конечно, можно и по-другому. Подберезовик - гриб, который растет в березовых лесах. Но тогда откуда* под*? Мое мнение подтверждает двухтомный словарь Тихонова.

Comment: Все-таки суффикс -овик? Он имеет отношение только к грибам или еще где-то используется?

Comment: Ну кто ж Вам однозначно ответит? Разный подход к анализу, даже в официальных справочниках разные версии. Это  важно - выбрать один вариант?

Comment: Если не секрет, для чего Вам нужен точный ответ? Может, тогда подскажем, как поступить.

Comment: Не секрет. В школе ребенок сказал, что слово образовано от слова"березовый" с помощью ПОД- и -ИК-. Мотивируя выбор тем, что -ОВ- уже есть. Но если есть -ОВИК-, похоже, учитель прав...

Comment: Ну вот Вам и другой подход: есть однокоренное слово с таким суффиксом, значит этот суффикс и выделяем. Но я с таким подходом не согласна. Приучена идти от значения слова. Так логичнее. В школе с детьми тоже выделила бы суффикс -овик-.

Answer (score 1):

Валгина Н.С., Розенталь Д.Э., Фомина М.И. в "Современном русском языке" в слове подберезовик выделяют **корень *берез-*** (ср. береза, березовый), **приставку под-** и **суффиксы ов- и ик** (ср. берез-ов-ый, березов-ик), а также **нулевое окончание** (ср. подберезовик, подберезовик-а, подберезо-вик-у и т.д.).

Comment: Спасибо. Но все-таки -ов- или -овик-?

Answer (score 1):

Словарь А.Н. Тихонова "Школьный словообразовательный словарь р.яз"
 дает такое членение: под-берез-овик от слова "береза"...

Answer (score 1):

Если подумать о детях, я бы выбрала вариант "от слова БЕРЕЗА", мне этот вариант кажется более прозрачным....

Answer (score 0):

При словообразовательном анализе всегда нужно постараться найти слово, которое отличалось бы от анализируемого минимум разных морфем. Обычно речь идет только об одной морфеме. В вашем случае таким словом должно быть прилагательное "подберёзовый". Остается  только уточнить, есть ли такое слово в русском языке. Я проделала эту работу, задав такой вопрос в Гугле и получив на него утвердительный, а главное,  убедительный ответ. Наряду со словосочетанием  "берёзовый сок", существует понятие "подберёзовый".  Сразу задаю себе вопрос: зачем это новое слово в нашем языке? В чем они разнятся в применении? Нахожу сама для себя следующий вариант ответа: 
- берёзовый сок,  апельсиновый сок и др 
- "подберёзовый"  указывает. скорее,  на способ его получения. 
И если наши современные словари еще не отобразили  это слово  в своих изданиях, ( в чем я  совсем не уверена, так как,  возможно, оно уже   в некоторых словарях есть), то это еще не значит, что такое слово не имеет право на существвоание в живом русском языке, который во все времена опережал словарный язык, Такова прекрасная участь любого языка, который постоянно обогащается , благодаря живому языку, новыми  словами,  отражающими новые понятия,  ( в данном случае, думаю,  речь идет, я бы сказала,  об уточняющем определении). 
Итак, привожу  словообразовательную цепочку рассматриваемого слова, а именно, слова  подберёзовик.
берёза- берёзовый- подберезовый- подберёзовик
Думаю, в этой цепочке прекрасно видна производящая основа подберезов - ( основа- это все слово без окончания) для  слова подберёзовик. 
Итак, лишь слово подберезовый  может являться производящим для производного от него слова подберезовик, отличаясь от производящего слова только одной морфемой: суффиксом -ик-, что на все сто соответствует основному требованию  ( минимум разных морфем) при поиске производящего слова. 
Успехов Вам в дальнейшем понимании нашего прекрасного языка, который, на жаль, засоряется многими ненужными для него словами, поскольку  русский язык имеет сам по себе неиссякаемые возможности для выражения самых разных понятий и представлений. 
Тами

Comment: Спасибо. А слово "подберёзовый" - для меня открытие...